# How Multiple Joins on Multiple Tables in One Query At SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work on a C# project that uses SQL Server.

I want to join on multiple tables in a query (OR run multiple statements in a single query)

My query is this :

```
(select HR.ID, HR.Cod, HR.CodeValed, H.Onvan, H.Model from HR LEFT JOIN H ON HR.ID_Sefat = H.ID) AAA;
SELECT GG.Cod G
FROM 
(Select * From AAA Where AAA.Model = 'M') MM
Left JOIN (Select * From AAA Where AAA.Model = 'K') KK ON MM.CodeValed = KK.Cod
Left JOIN (Select * From AAA Where AAA.Model = 'G') GG ON KK.CodeValed = GG.Cod
```

But it doesn't work, it returns an error.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Show what the table name with necessary column name and expected output. This question can't be solved if its in this way.

Comment: Well, for one: tell us **WHAT** the error is! Please show us the **exact and complete** error message

Comment: the error message is : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'AAA'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
with AAA as 
(select HR.ID, HR.Cod, HR.CodeValed, H.Onvan, H.Model from HR 
LEFT JOIN H ON HR.ID_Sefat = H.ID) 
SELECT GG.Cod G
FROM 
(Select * From AAA Where AAA.Model = 'M') MM
Left JOIN (Select * From AAA Where AAA.Model = 'K') KK ON MM.CodeValed = KK.Cod
Left JOIN (Select * From AAA Where AAA.Model = 'G') GG ON KK.CodeValed = GG.Cod
```